# Low sound volume on Lenovo laptop under Fedora

Tags: fedora, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm having trouble hearing anything at all under Fedora 16 on this Lenovo T520. Everything in alsamixer is at 100% (both pulseaudio and card). I installed Windows 7 on the laptop to check if the same issue is present on windows, and it's not.

Does anyone know how to deal with this? I've been annoyed by this problem for almost a year, but now with the heat wave on the east coast, I have to run my AC at full blast and I can't hear anything with the AC on.

Under audacity I can get definitely get high volume out of my speakers by just mixing up the sound volume. Is there a way to run a software amplifier between PulseAudio and alsa to crank up the volume or is there something that can be done in alsactl.conf to get the card to normalize the sound volume scale at a lower point? Since this laptop is quite common among Linux users, I would hope that someone has come up with a solution.

Comment: Or try a different kernel version? -- https://bugzilla.altlinux.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23705

Comment: Did you ever tried alsamixer through command line? some time GUIs doesn't work properly! I had same problem on my dell laptop which solved by justify PCM column to 100%.

Comment: Perhaps volume turned down with some physical wheel thingy? Happened to me once...

Comment: Do you use fedora 16 default (gnome)? Did you try `gnome-control-center sound` and maxing out the volume-bar at the bottom?

Comment: funny, i have an identical setup (520/F16) with no sound issues

Comment: @mattdm - is a solution using alsamixer and alsactl store acceptable? I have a T410 and typically set the preferences in gnome sound preferences to over 100% (150%) and then save it with `sudo alsactl store`.

Comment: @slm as long as I can put it somewhere it happens automatically and I don't ever have to think about it again :)

Comment: @mattdm if you're using pulse, [this](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=108501#p618403) might help.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this in the past and have had pretty good success with boosting the volume up. The only problem with it is if you turn it down, then you'll have to come back into the system preferences under the speaker icon to turn it back up to 150%.

However with the steps below should remain "sticky" from reboot to reboot.

[image: ss #1]

#### Turning up the volume

If you right click on the speaker applet and select sound preferences you'll bring up this dialog.

[image: ss #2]

#### confirming and saving changes

Turn the volume all the way up to 150%. Once it's been turned up you can close this dialog. If you go to a shell and type the command `amixer` you can confirm this:

```
$ amixer 
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 98304 [150%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 98304 [150%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 65536 [100%] [off]
  Front Right: Capture 65536 [100%] [off]
```

If you then run this command you can save this state out so that the next time you restart your system, it will be the default.

```
# saves settings
$ sudo alsactl store

# confirm file's created
$ ls -l /etc/asound.state 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4761 Oct  5 16:54 /etc/asound.state
```

#### Other things with amixer

You can use the command `amixer` to change the volume as well.

*100%*

```
$ amixer sset Master 100% | grep Front
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

*150%*

```
$ amixer sset Master 150% | grep Front
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

**NOTE:** This method doesn't allow you to go higher than 100%, however.

*mute*

```
$ amixer sset Master muted | grep Front
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [off]
```

*unmute*

```
$ amixer sset Master unmuted | grep Front
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
```

Comment: _"The only problem with it is if you turn it down, then you'll have to come back into the system preferences under the speaker icon to turn it back up to 150%."_ This is what I'd really like to avoid. What I want is for the speaker icon volume slider to be changed, either to have a higher maximum or to be permanently boosted.

Comment: @mattdm - I kind of figured that's what you were after but I figured I take a shot and provide this method that I've used. I'll keep digging, see if I can turn something else up.

Comment: @mattdm - this has frustrated me at times too. Seems like there should be something better, if you find anything out, even with the plugins route, please share back here. I'd be curious to know it too!

Comment: Did someone explain why it happens in the first place and why we can't just fix the issue instead of working around it?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda - you can see what was discussed about this through out this Q/A. No one ever mentions it and I've continued to use this workaround on Fedora 19 on the same hardware. I should mention that I've used this workaround maybe 2+ times since moving to F19 Dec/2014 so it's not like it's killing me.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: I actually started using it almost every day, that's why I'm interested in a fix. Bumping up the volume from the command line means that I cannot use normal volume controls to adjust the volume or it would go down to 100%.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda - what's your distro & hardware just for reference purposes? These issues can be tricky to debug w/o the actual H/W + distro.

Comment: Gentoo (mostly) stable with Lenovo T420s. I'm going to continue to use this machine or my Lenovo x201 which IMO had similar issues in the near future. I suspect the same issue applies to my old x61 as well.

Answer (score 4):

From what I know you can use the [softvol](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Softvol) plugin for ALSA and set the [`max_dB`](http://rene.bz/using-alsas-softvol-plugin-and-maxdb/) value. Something in direction of:

```
pcm.!default {
    type        plug
    slave.pcm   "softvol"
}

pcm.softvol {
    type    softvol
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        # pcm   "dmix" or this or the like.
    }
    control {
        name    "PreAmp"
        card    0
    }
    min_dB  -5.0
    max_dB  30.0  # 50.0 is max
    resolution 16
}
```

Perhaps some hints [here as well](http://alsa.opensrc.org/How_to_use_softvol_to_control_the_master_volume). Then reload alsa, play e.g. `speaker-test -c2 -twav` to get it loaded and then adjust amp in alsamixer.

If one want to shut down PulseAudio, remember to deactivate `autospawn`.

```
echo autospawn=no >> ~/.pulse/client.conf
```

or uncomment it in the global `client.conf` (in `/etc/pulse/` or the like). (Have also seen some replace `daemon-binary` with `/bin/true`.)

---

However using pactl etc. would perhaps be more preferable.

From commandline say:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 65536   # 100%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 98304   # 150%
pactl set-sink-volume 0 131072  # 200%
                      | |
                      | +----- Based on volume steps
                      +------- Sink number
```

To list and identify sinks say:

```
pactl list sinks
pacmd list-sinks # a bit more verbose, and list "volume steps"
```

As always `man` and `pacmd -h`, `pactl -h`.

---

To set default volume to e.g. 150% edit `./pulse/default.pa` and add the line:

```
set-sink-volume 0 98304
                |
                +-- (Use full name if one e.g. have multiple USB-soundcards.)
```

For convenience add an alias or a short script to set this value when ever you want.

To restart PA say `pulseaudio -k`, and `pulseaudio --start`.

---

Another option would be to look into plugins e.g. LADSPA and [shw](http://plugin.org.uk/swh-plugins/) in [ALSA](http://alsa.opensrc.org/LADSPA_plugins) or [PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/a/44151/101774).

---

**EDIT:**

OK. Came to think about it. This might be suitable. *(Don't know how it escaped me first time around.)*

1. In `default.pa` add a [Pulse Audio module](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) from Device Drivers.
2. Restart Pulse Audio.
3. Open *Sound settings* and set volume for *original sink* to e.g. 150%. (Or do this by commandline or pre-set it in `default.pa` as described above.)
4. Select the new module/sink as device for sound output.

This will give you 150% as 100% when using the *normal* volume meter.

Example – using [`module-remap-sink`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index12h3):

Do *not* uncomment as the doc say.

In `default.pa`:

```
.ifexists module-remap-sink.so
# Using remap-sink as dummy, not doing any re-mapping.
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=VolDummy master=0 sink_properties=device.description=CrankThaVolume
.fail
.endif

# Set it as default:
set-default-sink VolDummy
```

Then restart Pulse Audio to get the new module registered.

Issuing:

```
$ pactl list modules # Should show "Usage counter: 1" for the module in question.
$ pactl list sinks
```

should show a new sink. You can still crank the volume for *master* by using command-line and/or adding lines to `default.pa`.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the `set-sink-volume` approach is the best that can reasonably be done, and it doesn't address the real want. Oh well. I'll look into plugins and see what they might be able to do for me.

Comment: @mattdm: Yes. Added a new solution that might fit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

When running alsamixer from the command line, be sure to run with the `--view all` switch to ensure you're looking at all available mixer controls.

```
alsamixer -V all
```

Also, press F6 in alsamixer and check the settings for each device listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem one time in Fedora 18. Turned out Google's "pepperbox" API for Flash had some serious issues with sound, and I solved it by going into /home//.config/google-chrome and killing PepperFlash, then reinstalling flash plugins from Adobe.