# Setting maximum volume

Tags: audio, alsa

I usually work in a WM (i.e., i3wm) and use `alsamixer` to adjust sound volume.

The recent Linux installation on a Dell t5500 machine gives a very loud sound when set the maximum volume in `alsamixer`. It would damage my eardrum, if I mistakenly set the volume to be maximum as I usually use in-ear earphone. Is there anyway to set the peak sound volume?

Comment: Might be helpful/related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42561/low-sound-volume-on-lenovo-laptop-under-fedora/93735#93735

Answer (score 1):

not directly.

the only way i can think of, is by using a "virtual soundcard" that applies some pre-amplification (<1. so it's actually a pre-damping). thus when you set the volume to `100%` (of your virtual soundcard) you actually have a softer volume setting in the real soundcard.

something like the following `~/.asoundrc` (untested):

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm amp
}

pcm.amp {
  type plug
  slave.pcm "plughw"
  ttable {
    0.0 = 0.7 #amplication factor for channel 0/0
    1.1 = 0.7 #amplication factor for channel 1/1
  }
}
```

see [asoundrc](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Asoundrc) for more info on how to write a proper asoundrc.