# How to set an upper bound on volume in PulseAudio?

Tags: pulseaudio

Is it possible to set an upper limit for PulseAudio on startup? I would like to make sure that I do not put the volume too high for the sake of my eardrums.

I looked into `pactl set-sink-volume` but that doesn't allow me to set a maximum volume limit. As well I cannot find anything under `man pactl`.

Comment: Here is another person asking the same question (also unanswered, unfortunately): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188808/set-maximum-volume-in-arch-linux — there is a cheap hardware solution, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by the following bash code

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(pactl list sinks | grep '^[[:space:]]Volume:' | head -n $(( $SINK + 1 )) | tail -n 1 | sed -e 's,.* \([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*,\1,' )
if [[ $x -le 200 ]]
then
    pactl set-sink-volume 0 +5% 
fi
```

In this volume is stored in variable x

Comment: What is `$SINK`?