# Disable setting volume above 100% in pulseaudio

Tags: debian, pulseaudio

In some programs it's possible to set the audio output volume above 100%. It seems to be supported by Pulseaudio up to ridiculous amounts. How can I fix this so 100% is the absolute limit?

Rationale: More than 100% is stupid, breaks sound completely (unless you have some other serious problem with your audio which you are trying to fix this way {don't do it like this}) and recently it was set too high even at boot time.

Related: [Setting up maximum volumes even lower than 100%](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284732/how-to-set-an-upper-bound-on-volume-in-pulseaudio) (no answer so far) and [setting the volume even higher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219739/adjust-max-possible-volume-in-pulseaudio).

Comment: Your question is fair, but what about when you want to play music which (due to being recorded at too low of a gain) never exceeds a certain amplitude in the recording? You can play back at greater than 100% volume to "fix" that.

Comment: @Celada Adding Replay Gain information to the file would be one way, or re-encoding it already normalized. Ideally, you'll go complain to the person who mastered that track and tell them they did a poor job. Personally I'm using an external audio input/output device which has physical loudness knobs which I usually turn to change volume, leaving the digital setting permanently at 100% (unless I accidentally set it to more than 100% and get nothing but noise... -.-).

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04, whether the volume slider allows setting the volume above 100% is controlled by the following dconf key. Run the following command to disallow setting the volume above 100%. Change takes effect immediately.

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.sound allow-amplified-volume false
```

Comment: > Change takes effect

Nope :(

Comment: @yPhil . When you have the Sound settings window open and you run the command with `false` or `true`, you should see the "Allow louder than 100%" checkbox toggle. What do you see when you run the commands?

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu MATE 18.04