# How can I increase volume level on Ubuntu?

Tags: audio

I have Levono ideapad L340 with Ubuntu. I would like to increase volume level. Alsamixer and Ubuntu's volume level shows maximum. Is there any other way to increase the level?

Comment: Run `pavucontrol`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be resolved already. Check

[Low sound volume on Lenovo laptop under Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42561/low-sound-volume-on-lenovo-laptop-under-fedora/93735#93735)

[Setting maximum volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116084/setting-maximum-volume)